# Manual network setting on Solaris 10

Tags: networking, solaris, network-interface

I am using Solaris 10 on VirtualBox. While installing I chose to assign IP manually.

```
IP address: 192.168.1.46
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.1.1
```

Now when I ping my Solaris machine with other machine reply is coming, but I am not able to connect to the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

With Solaris 10 you need to edit `/etc/resolv.conf` and:

```
cp /etc/nsswitch.dns /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

Also I am assuming you have a bridged network in VirtualBox. If you have Host only it won't work. But as a test try to `ping 8.8.8.8` Google DNS server if you can then the solution stated above will work, otherwise you don't have routing to Internet and need. To fix that first.